# Knockout CSS databinding using a function?

Tags: css, data-binding, knockout.js

I have the following **working code** that uses Knockout to determine what color to render a state in the 2012 Presidential election. If the state value is 1 (Republican), the color is *red*. If the state value is 2 (Democrat), the color is *blue*. If the state value is 3 (Toss Up), the color is *yellow*.

```
<div class="el-clickable" data-bind="css: { 
'el-republican': model.ny()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.republican, 
'el-democrat': model.ny()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.democrat, 
'el-tossup': model.ny()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.tossUp 
}" 
state-abbrev="ny" style="top:26px;left:442px;height:102px;width:54px;" title="New York">
<div style="margin-top:46px;">NY</div></div>

<div class="el-clickable" data-bind="css: { 
'el-republican': model.pa()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.republican, 
'el-democrat': model.pa()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.democrat, 
'el-tossup': model.pa()===ip.constants.electoralStatusValue.tossUp 
}" 
state-abbrev="pa" style="top:107px;left:372px;height:65px;width:65px;" title="Pennsylvania">
<div style="margin-top:23px;">PA</div></div>
```

The problem is that this seems like such a **brute force approach** to the problem since I need to have **3 separate CSS binding calls** in order to fetch a single CSS selector. That is, I need to check for republican, democrat and tossup for each state on my electoral college map.

(The real-world scenario is even worse as I actually check for republican, leaning republican, democrat, leaning democrat, undecided, tossup, and locked!)

http://www.ipredikt.com/contests/election2012

What I really want is a way to achieve this by calling a utility function and passing in the state value, like this:

```
data-bind="css: getStateColor(model.pa())" // for Pennsylvania
```

Is this doable with the 'attr' binding?

I've often felt that the **CSS binding mechanism** of: 'string-literal', true|false **is very restrictive**. I wish Knockout also supported something like:

```
data-bind="css: myFunction(myParam)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout 2.2, coming out very soon (10/26/2012) will support this with the `css` binding. Until then, you can use this [`class`](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) binding to do the same thing.

Comment: Awesome answer! Didn't get a chance to respond until to today. Implemented this fix over the weekend, and I couldn't believe how much faster my Election 2012 widget became! Here's a link to a partner site using our Knockout-based widget - prior to this change, load latency was over 2 seconds. Now, it's significantly faster, almost as fast as the host page. Thanks you for this EXCELLENT solution. Can't wait for 2.2, but until then, this one-off fix is perfect. Two thumbs up! http://mynorthwest.com/category/electoral_map

Comment: 2.2 was released this morning. Looks like a great widget.